# Google Play Store stuck on "Pending" (Android 10)

Tags: google-play-store, cache

The issue with Google Play Store being stuck on "Pending" has been discussed a lot. [We all know the solution: clear the cache](https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-resolve-the-play-store-download-pending-issue/).

But I'd like to delve deeper into this problem. I'd appreciate a serious explanation:

1. Am I doomed to forever needing to clear the cache before ever doing anything with Play Store? All the "clear your cache" solutions posted on the Internet kind of imply that you should do this once, or at worst maybe once every several months. But me, I need to install stuff from the Store thrice a day! And it just doesn't work unless I clear the cache each and every time.
2. What crime have I committed that my Android behaves this way? Why do some phones do and some don't? Why isn't Google able to come up with the solution for this seemingly simple issue after all these years? Is there some workaround that I'm not aware of? After all, one (not me) could write a macro or something that automatically clears the cache when you click on Store. Would you advise me to purchase a new phone? It's very difficult to work like this.

Thanks y'all!